# How do I recover an a .xlsx file from its corrupted type:file form?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was working on an Excel file on my Windows. Little did I notice that it was actually pulled from my iCloud Drive that I linked from my MacBook to Windows laptop. Anyway, it refused to sync and I cannot open nor recover the file from both laptops. There's not even a recoverable temporary file on Excel, and I don't have a duplicate of it. Previously it was an .xlsx file and now it just says file. Trying to open it on Mac puts me through the TextEdit and not Excel while on Windows, it refused being open entirely.

Comment: You need to compare the file as text with a good file and find out where the difference is : If it's only some text headers or whether the file's contents are now rubbish. `.xlsx` files are Zip files, so zip-reparation utilities could help after you rename the file to `.zip`.